# Avoid code duplication in JSP

Tags: jsp, code-reuse, code-duplication

I am using JSP and Spring framework. In a page, I want to have five buttons next to a corresponding `select` element. My question is how can I avoid repeating the code for that?

Here is the code I have for one button-select combination:

```
       <tr>
            <td>
                <sf:label path="inputFile">Select a file:</sf:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <sf:select path="inputFile" cssStyle="width: 250px;" onchange="enableLocal(this.selectedIndex,'matButton')">
                    <sf:option value="Upload a Local File" />
                    <sf:option value=" --- Available already: --- " disabled="true" />
                    <sf:options items="${flowData.availableInputs}" />
                </sf:select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="matButton" type="file" name="inputFile"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

In the above code, the names `inputFile` and `matButton` are to be treated as parameters, i.e., other buttons will have different names.

What I have in mind is something like a function with the two parameters that would generate the above code. Is it possible?

Comment: Unrelated, but You shouldn't be using TABLES for layouts. Use LABELS and a re-styled unordered list. See: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a [custom JSP tag file](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaiy.html).

`/WEB-INF/tags/file.tag`

```html
<%@ tag body-content="empty" %>
<%@ attribute name="selectPath" required="true" type="java.lang.String" %>
<%@ attribute name="buttonId" required="true" type="java.lang.String" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sf" uri="...???..." %>

<tr>
    <td>
        <sf:label path="${selectPath}">Select a file:</sf:label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <sf:select path="${selectPath}" cssStyle="width: 250px;" onchange="enableLocal(this.selectedIndex,'${buttonId}')">
            <sf:option value="Upload a Local File" />
            <sf:option value=" --- Available already: --- " disabled="true" />
            <sf:options items="${flowData.availableInputs}" />
        </sf:select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="${buttonId}" type="file" name="inputFile"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

*(I have no idea what that `sf` taglib is, you've to complete its URI yourself)*

Use it as follows where `file` is the base filename of the `.tag` file:

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="my" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
...
<my:file selectPath="inputFile" buttonId="matButton" />
```

Comment: Does file.tag need to be in /WEB-INF/tags? Or can I also put it next to my jsp files in WEB-INF/jsp?

Comment: The path is free to your choice. Don't forget to alter `tagdir` accordingly. I'd only recommend to not mix JSP pages and JSP tags in the same folder as this is confusing for the average maintainer who respects the standard conventions.

Answer (score 1):

As written above, you can use custom tag jsp. Then, you can declare somewhere in a model all pairs (`inputFile` & `matButton`) you want to use, and use core tag libs (`<c:forEach>`). Refer to this [example](http://www.crazysquirrel.com/computing/java/jsp/jstl-forEach.jspx). This will iterate over your collection which contains label definitions (all these actions you can make from a controller).